# How to find out which numbers sum was made of if we are able to choose the form of numbers

Tags: math

I need to pass 5-digit ids to external service and find out what ids were passed if service only shows the sum of all ids passed and the largest possible number service can show is 10**15 with 15 digits after the decimal point.

So, obvious solution is to pass each next number with digits never used before, like

123450000000000.000000000000000

000001234500000.000000000000000

...

000000000000000.000000000012345

Thus, with such kind if approach our limit is 6 ids. Is it possible to achieve better results with any technique?

Comment: 5-digit id is any 5-digit number starting from a nonzero digit. Nonzero digits don't have to be consecutive. This service performing addition exactly

Comment: 1. What is the range of possible IDs? Any number from 10000 to 99999? 2. Are the IDs unique? In your example, every ID is 12345. 3. Can you constrain the range of IDs you pass to the service? Or do you need a solution which works for any IDs from the allowed range? 4. How can you shift the passed IDs? In the example you don't pass 12345 five times, you pass 123450000000000, 1234500000, 12345, 0.12345, 0.0000012345 and 0.000000000012345. These are not 5-digit IDs...

Comment: Range of possible IDs - 10000-99999. IDs are unique. In my example id 12345 is just for example. I need a solution that works for any ID from the allowed range.  I pass 12345 with different decimal places just to show my simple solution to this problem. The main thing - I need to pass as many unique 5-digit ids as possible considering the service restriction of 15 decimal places both before point and after the point.